# Why does Windows use backslashes for paths and Unix forward slashes?

Tags: windows, unix, path

It annoys me having used Unix in college and now working on the Windows side. What's the history behind this decision? Anyone know why it worked out this way?

Comment: [Slash versus backslash as directory separator - what/who caused this rift?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4695/1981)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Unix introduced `/` as the directory separator sometime around 1970. I don't know why exactly this character was chosen; the ancestor system Multics used `>`, but the designers of Unix had already used `>` together with `<` for redirection in the shell (see [Why is the root directory denoted by a `/` sign?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103471/why-is-the-root-directory-denoted-by-a-sign/103484#103484)).

[MS-DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) 2.0 introduced `\` as the directory separator in the early 1980s. The reason `/` was not used is that MS-DOS 1.0 (which did not support directories at all) was already [using `/` to introduce command-line options](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/master/v1.25/source/COMMAND.ASM#L787). It probably took this usage of `/` from [VMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) (which had a more complicated syntax for [directories](https://wiki.vmssoftware.com/Directory)). You can read a more detailed explanation of why that choice was made [on Larry Osterman's blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/why-is-the-dos-path-character). MS-DOS even briefly had an option to change the option character to `-` and the directory separator to `/`, but it didn't stick.

`/` it is recognized by most programmer-level APIs (in all versions of DOS and Windows). So you can often, but not always get away with using `/` as a directory separator under Windows. A notable exception is that [you can't use `/` as a separator after the `\\?` prefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx) which (even in Windows 7) is the only way to specify a path using Unicode or containing more than 260 characters.

Some user interface elements support `/` as a directory separator under Windows, but not all. Some programs just pass filenames through to the underlying API, so they support `/` and `\` indifferently. In the command interpreter (in `command.com` or `cmd`), you can use `/` in many cases, but not always; this is partly dependent on the version of Windows (for example, `cd /windows` works in XP and 7 but did not in Windows 9x). The Explorer path entry box accepts `/` (at least from XP up; probably because it also accepts URLs). On the other hand, the standard file open dialog [rejects slashes](https://superuser.com/questions/441210/can-i-use-a-slash-in-the-windows-open-file-dialog).

Comment: `/` is recognized as a directory separator by the MS-DOS or Windows command-line.

Comment: "C:\Windows\System32>cd /windows/system" works.

Comment: @TomWij: Do you have a reference as to where precisely `/` is accepted on the command line? For example, what does `dir /p` do? and `dir c:/p`? and `c:/windows/notepad.exe`? and `start /windows/notepad.exe`? etc. (I don't have a Windows machine here to test.)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx - File I/O functions in the Windows API convert "/" to "\" as part of converting the name to an NT-style name, except when using the "\\?\" prefix as detailed in the following sections. - The command line uses this File I/O functions.

Comment: @Andrew: thanks. All I could scrounge up on short notice is a Windows 98, where `cd /windows` does not work.

Comment: `/` was probably used as the directory separator in UNIX because it was an easy (unshifted) key to strike on a Teletype.  The unshifted special characters were `: - ; , . /`.

Comment: It should be noted that MS-DOS was a rebranding of QDOS (Quick and Dirty OS) produced by Seattle Computer Products.  QDOS, in turn, was written to mimic CP/M-86.  I don't know whether either of those products used `/` for options, though.

Comment: @DanielRHicks CP/M used `/` for options, and that is indeed where DOS got it from (as I mention in my answer).

Comment: CP/M didn't get anything from VMS.  Perhaps the other way around.  CP/M was first written in 1975.  VMS was not even a dream then.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I recently dug through DOS 1 and 2 sources and manuals and found out that Microsoft used `/` (and `-` for switches) like Xenix, and inspired by Xenix, but IBM released before Microsoft shipped to OEMs, and IBM used `\` (and `/` for switches) and changed the prompt from `A:` to `A>` so they changed the default and shipped buggy (still assuming `/`/`-`) documentation plus a note that it was changed and why.

Comment: IIRC, Unix introduced `/` because its development went hand-in-hand with the C language, where the backslash is used in escape sequences.

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm Using `/` as leading separator would be very bad practice. I just tested with `\d`, `\dd`, and `\tt` as directory names: while `cd /tt` works, `cd /d` gives an error, and `cd /dd` enters the `\d` directory!—This said, `cd D:/dd` works well.

Comment: @GregA.Woods Later versions of CP/M came after VMS was well-established, but even [CP/M 3](http://www.cpm.z80.de/manuals/cpm3-cmd.pdf) doesn't seem to have used `/` as an option specifier. So I seem to have unwittingly propagated an urban legend, sorry about 
that. `/` for options actually didn't come via CP/M, it came directly from VMS (or perhaps some other DEC or IBM system, it seems that people don't remember the reason anymore, or perhaps it was the combined influence of multiple systems).

Answer (score 11):

The [underlying Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx) can accept either the backslash or slash to separate directory and file components of a path, but the Microsoft convention is to use a backslash, and APIs that return paths put backslash in.

[MS-DOS 2.0](http://www.wordiq.com/definition/MS-DOS) copied the hierarchical file system from Unix and thus used the forward slash, but (possibly on the insistence of [IBM](http://www.ibm.com)) added the backslash to allow paths to be typed into the command shell while retaining compatibility with [MS-DOS 1.0](http://www.wordiq.com/definition/MS-DOS) and [CP/M](http://www.cpm.z80.de/) where the slash was the command-line option indicator.

- Compare `dir/w`, which shows the current directory in wide format, against `dir\w`, which runs the file `w` within the `dir` directory.

References:

- [Wikipedia: Backslash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash)
- [Larry Osterman's WebLog](http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2005/06/24/432386.aspx)