# How does `pushd` exactly behave regarding path with slashes `/`?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe, cd

Consider the following commands given from a cmd prompt:

```
D:\test>cd D:/

D:\>cd /test

D:\test>pushd D:/
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

D:\test>pushd "D:/"

D:\>popd

D:\test>cd ..

D:\>pushd /test
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

D:\>pushd "/test"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

D:\>pushd "D:/test"

D:\test>
```

It seems that `cd` process correctly slashes `/` in general, while `pushd` only accepts them only if at the same time:

- The argument is quoted
- The full path is given

Does this correspond to truth? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: The funny thing is that changing to the `/?` directory using `cd /?` can give you some help with the `cd` command

Comment: @infixed Yep! :) And you cannot change to a hypothetical folder named `D` by doing `cd /D` as that is a valid `cd` option.

Comment: It looks like you are using the `cmd` shell in Microsoft's Windows, therefore you have to put the slash the wrong way around. (This is because of a historical accident, there the slash was used to give options. It seemed like a good idea at the time, as Microsoft had not heard of directories at this time, (or of windowing systems, or networks)).

Comment: Windows doesn’t really do forward slashes. They’re traditionally used to indicate switches on the command line. So while your question might be academically interesting, it’s not really about a problem.

Comment: @DanielB I wonder then why they didn't simply implement functions to give error in case `/` was used (without a valid option). My use case concerns paths generated by `cmake` to be used in a configure file generating a batch script.

Answer (score 3):

Read MSDN article [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions):

**Naming Conventions** The following fundamental rules enable applications to create and process valid names for files and directories, regardless of the file system:

- Use a period to separate the base file name from the extension in the name of a directory or file.
- Use a **backslash** (`\`) to separate the components of a path. The backslash divides the file name from the path to it, and one directory name from another directory name in a path. You cannot use a backslash in the name for the actual file or directory because it is a reserved character that separates the names into components.
- Use a backslash as required as part of volume names, for example, the "`C:\`" in "`C:\path\file`" or the "`\\server\share`" in "`\\server\share\path\file`" for Universal Naming Convention (UNC) names. For more information about UNC names, see the [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) section.
- …

More reading on `(\)/` *(reverse) solidus*: [Why does Windows use backslashes for paths and Unix forward slashes?](https://superuser.com/a/176395/376602)

In the command interpreter (`cmd.exe`), you can use `/` as a separator of path components in many cases, but not always. Example:

```
==> d:\bat\so\second.bat a b c
second.bat parameters: %*=a b c

==> d:/bat/so/second.bat a b c
second.bat parameters: %*=a b c

==> type d:/bat/so/second.bat
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

==> type "d:/bat/so/second.bat"
The system cannot find the file specified.

==> type d:/bat/so\second.bat
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

==> type "d:/bat/so\second.bat"
@echo %~nx0 parameters: %%*=%*

==>
```

Another example:

```
==> dir d:/bat/so/second.bat
Parameter format not correct - "bat".

==> dir "d:/bat/so/second.bat"
 Volume in drive D is DataDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 4288-6B27

 Directory of d:\bat\so

File Not Found

==> dir "d:/bat/so\second.bat"
 Volume in drive D is DataDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 4288-6B27

 Directory of d:\bat\so

27.11.2015  17:35                32 second.bat
               1 File(s)             32 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  910 153 654 272 bytes free

==>
```

Comment: The last example is amazing! :)